# Cycling through CSS Post classes in Tumblr

Tags: javascript, html, css, styles, tumblr

I am trying to style my `{block:Photo}` styles in Tumblr, so that each time a photo is posted, it will cycle through a selection of, for instance, 5 slightly different classes for displaying the picture.

An example of such can be found here (where each photo table has a unique `max-width` property): http://www.nontemporary.com/

The code I've come up with so far, having made ample use of the Chrome inspector is thus:

```
            {block:Posts}

            {block:Photo}

                <li class="post photo">

                    <table width="100%" align="left" valign="top" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                        <tbody>
                            <tr class="postspace">
                                <td></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr class="postrow">
                                <td class="postdistrict">
                                 <img src="{PhotoURL-HighRes}" alt="{PhotoAlt}" align="left" valign="top" class="post1">
                                <td>
                                 <td class="postdistrict">
                                 <img src="{PhotoURL-HighRes}" alt="{PhotoAlt}" align="left" valign="top" class="post1">
                                <td>
                            </tr>

                        </tbody>
                     </table>

                </li>
            {/block:Photo}


        {/block:Posts}
```

Naturally, I think I'll have to create some custom classes for the widths, but my main question is really how I should go about getting Tumblr to cycle through those widths, as can be seen in the example.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want them to cycle through the classes in order (like the example does) you can utilise the fact that tumblr [lets you style each number of post](https://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/custom_themes#posts).

Here is an example of what you would do:

```
<li class="post-{block:Post1}1{/block:Post1}{block:Post2}2{/block:Post2}[...]{block:Post15}15{/block:Post15}">
```

This would render as

```
<li class="post-1">
```

with the 1 depending on what number post it is.

From here you can easily make classes for `.post-1` through to `.post-15`.

If you would like something random instead, javascript/jquery will be needed.

Comment: Thanks for your help Chloe! Actually, I'm pretty sure that I found your blog post about exactly this last night which helped me a great deal! Are there any ways to make Tumblr 'close the loop' after, say, `{/block:Post5}`, rather than having to go all the way to Post 15?

Comment: Haha wouldn't surprise me :P Unfortunately not, but you could always use `li:nth-of-type(5n + 1)`, `li:nth-of-type(5n + 2)`, `li:nth-of-type(5n + 3)`, `li:nth-of-type(5n + 4)` and `li:nth-of-type(5n + 5)` instead of manually doing it. This will loop through groups of 5 and should work with things like infinite scroll.

Comment: So based on that piece of advice above I spent a rather silly amount of time trying to get it working... and finally I've got it! Thanks for sending me on a rather helpful crash course on CSS syntax! Also, your themes are ace! Keep up the good work! Thanks again!